# Redis 4.0.14 AOF and RDB Restore

Tags: redis

I have enabled both RDB and AOF backup via `save 1 1` and `appendonly yes`. This configuration creates both RDB and AOF files, at prescribed locations. However, during restart of Redis the following is noticed

If `appendonly yes`, then RDB file is not read, regardless as to whether AOF file exists or not
If `appendonly no`, then RDB file is read

I've tested the above by setting `appendonly yes` and running `rm /persistent/redis/appendonly.aof; systemctl restart redis`. The log file shows

```
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16292]: 16292:M 13 Aug 11:11:06.199 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16292]: DB saved on disk
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16292]: Removing the pid file.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16292]: Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp systemd[1]: redis.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp systemd[1]: Stopped redis.service.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp systemd[1]: Starting redis.service...
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-check-aof[16354]: Cannot open file: /persistent/redis/appendonly.aof
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:C 13 Aug 11:11:06.232 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:C 13 Aug 11:11:06.233 # Redis version=4.0.14, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=16355, just started
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: Redis version=4.0.14, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=16355, just started
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:C 13 Aug 11:11:06.234 # Configuration loaded
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: Configuration loaded
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:C 13 Aug 11:11:06.234 * supervised by systemd, will signal readiness
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: supervised by systemd, will signal readiness
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp systemd[1]: Started redis.service.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:M 13 Aug 11:11:06.239 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16355]: Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:M 13 Aug 11:11:06.241 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16355]: Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:M 13 Aug 11:11:06.242 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16355]: WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:M 13 Aug 11:11:06.242 # Server initialized
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16355]: Server initialized
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis-server[16355]: 16355:M 13 Aug 11:11:06.242 * Ready to accept connections
Aug 13 11:11:06 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16355]: Ready to accept connections
```

Notice that the excepted message

```
...
Aug 13 11:26:53 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16616]: DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
Aug 13 11:26:53 saltspring-zynqmp redis[16616]: Ready to accept connections
```

is missing. To get RDB read, `appendonly` must be set to `no`.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Comment: That's the expected behavior. AOF file has a higher priority than RDB file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953542/aof-and-rdb-backups-in-redis) for more discussion on AOF and RDB.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does this mean that on restart, redis service needs to check for existence of AOF file and decide to whether restore from RDB or AOF, via redis-server cli options?

Comment: No. If AOF is on, it always recover from AOF, no matter whether AOF file exist or not. Check the link I gave above for detail.